# How to avoid calling String.Replace() in a loop?

Tags: c#, design, efficiency

I am building a very simple email templating system in C#, and it works amazingly, but  I have a personal issue with the way I designed it:

Template looks like this:

```
Hello {UserName},
Welcome to ....
```

And the way I am replacing the tokens with values is this:

```
foreach (var variable in variables)
{
    str = str.Replace("{" + variable.Key + "}", variable.Value);
}
```

Well, to say the least, I hate it. Is there any more efficient way of dealing with tokens?

**UPDATE: Found this article, and looks like both REGEX and StringBuilder are slower than String.Replace();**

[StringBuilder.Replace VS REGEX.Replace vs String.Replacte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/debuggingtoolbox/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance)

Comment: That doesn't look to be recursive.  It also replaces *all* values for the key (not just the first one). It looks rather reasonable at 0th glance, but the rest of the design would be needed to really say "yes this is good" or "no this isn't that great" and that might be a better question for Code Review once you have complete and working code.

Comment: @MichaelT Sorry, used wrong word "recursion" here. It's rather a loop of String.Replace. Edited. I am happy with the rest of the design, it's just I was looking if there are any alternatives - may be even something like this: String.Replace(KeyValuePair<string, string> whatToReplace)

Comment: You are likely looking for [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than trying to roll your own.  A [guide for its use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting).

Comment: @MichaelT I thought about it, but my templates might contain the same token in multiple places, and String.Format does not know about the mapping between token and it's value - it's merely based on order of arguments.

Comment: No, but unless you *really* work at optimizing it, String.Format will likely be faster.  Furthermore, it is likely to be more maintainable by the next programmer who has to deal with this code. Lastly, it greatly reduces the cognitive load when reading or modifying the code.  Oh yea,  and possibility of bugs in your code.

Comment: If your only justification for avoiding String.Format is lack of named parameter support, consider using James Newton's [FormatWith2.0](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables) code instead.  It's a very simple wrapper around `String.Format` that uses a regex to convert arbitrary named parameters to ordinal parameters.  It even supports complex named parameters (e.g., `{Results[0].Name}`).

Comment: If performance is a major concern, [Phil Haack rewrote it without regular expressions](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx/) .  Though at that point it's probably not that different from what I'd expect you to come up with by following the advice of the current answers, other than the use of databinder to support complex named parameters.

Comment: " to say the least, I hate it." - why do you hate a clean and simple solution? Do you have a **measurable** performance impact? How many variables do you expect?

Comment: @DocBrown It's not the variables, it's the size of emails that I hate traversing again and again.

Comment: You did not answer my question - the one in "bold"!

Comment: No I don't really. I just feel with my gut that there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Your gut is probably wrong, and what you found in that article might also not be correct when applied to your situation. When it comes to performance, **measure by yourself**, everything else is looking into a crystal bowl.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. In my case my system is not very heavy loaded, but felt like I am obligated to search for options :)

Comment: @Alexus, be careful with that article. Its not actually comparing the techniques discussed here.

Comment: You should hate it.  By doing repeated replaces you don't separate cleanly your template from your data.  If your template is "Name: {name}" and someone managed to register "John {privateKey} Doe" as a name, then he might receive the value of a privateKey which perhaps he was not supposed to see.  It shows the method is flawed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you need tokens.

One possible way to improve things is to look at each character in input the text (the templates) only once.

Search through the string from start to finish (once), and assemble a new string as follows: from the start, search for {, followed by identifier characters, then }.  Move the string text before the { to the new string, then look up the identifier in a dictionary and move the replacement to the new string.  Start over looking for { from where you left off last.

This way you're not scanning the input text over and over.  You could tokenize the input string, but I don't think it helps compared to this suggestion.

The point here is to think about how things scale (think O() descriptions).  If some template is very large then you're scanning that text once for each str.Replace operation. Further, if the number of variables is very large, then you're scanning a large input text as many times as the number of variables.  With this suggestion, you scan the input text only once, no matter how many variables.

Comment: Brilliant, this ensures I do scan the string once indeed, which seems to be the most expensive operation in the whole cycle.

Comment: Is the scan really the biggest hit? I suspect that since string is immutable, you are having a rather large hit for object copies with that replace call. I think if you implement something like the above answer and then also switch to StringBuilder.replace for mutable strings (or some mutable methodology), you will perhaps have better performance.

Comment: And you can still use IndexOf instead of scanning the string yourself, of course.

Comment: @JTrana, agreed, string builder is probably the way to build the replacement string.  Also, good observation that the object allocation & copy overhead could be quite large with multiple string.Replaces, as each loop would be required to return a string object even if it internally itself uses string builders.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this is using regular expressions:

```
string LookupVariable(Match match) {
   string name = match.Groups[1].Value;
   return variables[name];
}

str = (new Regex("{([^}]*)}")).Replace(str, LookupVariable);
```

I don't actually code C#, so my syntax is almost certainly not quite right.

Comment: Wouldn't that be slower or identical than StringBuilder replace?

Comment: @Alexus, if by that you mean calling .Replace() repeatedly on a StringBuilder, then no. Calling Replace() repeatedly will scan the string multiple times, whereas this will only scan the string once.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Regex replace might as well be doing similar thing to what @Erik Eidt suggested.

Comment: @Alexus, yes it'll end up being basically the same algorithm. The reason I'd consider this is just because it doesn't require you to manually write the logic he's describing.

Comment: And that's why I am interested ;) I will test tomorrow which one suits better.

Comment: I took the freedom to improve this answer syntactically. Note that this answer deals only with the case where you are sure the templates do not contain any other placeholders than the expected (which is probably the case here).

Comment: Way faster than regular Replace. Thanks!